# am getting a popup in my browser after running te code says : an error occurred

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10d9c.png)i don't know why am getting an error to get my `urls` right when i add `chat/` to my project but getting it working when i change my urls to `''` when i have the main application in my `urls.py` already with `''`.
**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('chat/', include('chat.urls')),]
```

**app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='index'),
    path('<str:room>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('checkview', views.checkview, name='checkview'),
    path('send', views.send, name='send'),
    path('getMessages/<str:room>/', views.getMessages, name='getMessages'),
]
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.darker {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container img.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right:0;
}

.time-right {
  float: right;
  color: #aaa;
}

.time-left {
  float: left;
  color: #999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
    <h2>Kan'nan Chat</h2>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <style>
    input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
    }

    div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    }
    </style>

    <form id="post-form" method="POST" action="checkview">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Room Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="room_name" id="room_name" width="100px" />
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" width="100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enter Room">
    </form>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're working on Python Backend Tutorial from FreeCodeCamp because I encountered the same error while working on it, which led me to this post.

For me, commenting out the ajax scripts on room.html got rid of the pop-up error which occurred to me when I reached the page after entering the "Room Name" and "Username" on the homepage. Because the message part of the app was not completed the ajax scripts were throwing errors.